# Different Networks on same interface in virtual box

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, nat

I have two VMs connected to the same internal network in virtual box. This internal network is connected to a NAT.

The DHCP server is giving an IP only for one VM. I want to configure the other one statically and stop dhcp option on it.

I want to have two different network IPs for the two machines.

The question is: how can I configure the two VMs on the same interface created between internal network and NAT? (having one main interface and two sub-interfaces with different IPs).